# Redirect subfolder if folder name is not 'blogparty' and prefix starts with 'blog'

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want a redirect to happen if subfolder prefix is 'blog' and 'X' is not equal to 'party'.

This should not redirect

```
http://www.hostname.co.uk/blogs/blogparty
```

---

This should redirect

```
http://www.hostname.co.uk/blogs/blogX
```

to

```
http://www.hostname.co.uk/blogs/X
```

where 'X' is any string which does not equal to 'party'.

---

This should work on sub directories of this directory as well meaning this should be redirected too.

```
http://www.hostname.co.uk/blogs/blogX/blah/index.php
```

to

```
http://www.hostname.co.uk/blogs/X/blah/index.php
```

---

This is what i tried which is redirecting everything including 'blogparty'

```
# Redirect blogBLOGNAME to BLOGNAME excluding blogparty
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs/blogparty/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs/blogparty$
RewriteRule ^/blogs/blog(.*) /blogs/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Should /blogs/blog throw 404?

Comment: that will be handled by other routes, i am only concerned with the redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules should have worked. I believe there are other routing rules below your shown rule. To handle this you can have your rule based on `THE_REQUEST` instead (which doesn't change after other rules):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+blogs/blogparty(/\S*)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blogs)/blog(.+)$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: This should work. I think the current set of rules are just recursing.